# How to Add Animated gif Splash Screen for QML Android Apps?

Tags: android, qt, qml

I would like to add animated gif splash screen because first installation takes too much time for old Android devices. I couldn't find any docs or clue about this. 
I especially would like to use this library: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable
I don't know anything about Java or layout.xml so I failed to use it for Qml app. If there is a simple hello world example it would be great!

Comment: Just show `Window` with animation from your main screen. But remember that your task should be running in a separate thread. Otherwise the GUI will be blocked.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do splash screen animation with qml, it is nice for desktop however black screen lasts untill all Qt libs installed on Android. I think gif animation requires to be loaded with java or xml way,

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a proposal about how to make animated QML splashscreen on Android.
Basically the solution mix two steps that allow to have a "partially" animated splash screen but don't use an animated git. Instead show the standard busy QML control. Is not what you are looking for but it could be a good base to improve with your need...

[QML: Mixed native Android and QML animated splash screen](https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2018/04/qml-mixed-native-android-and-qml.html)